# If a function is surjective, does it also mean there exist an inverse function?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a function $f: M \rightarrow N$ is surjective, does it also mean it has an inverse? or is it the same thing?

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, it has a *right* inverse, i.e. a function $g$ such that $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: $f$ needs to be bijection (=surjection and injection) for $f^{-1}$ to exist.

Comment: It'll have an inverse if it's bijective, which requires that $f $ be both surjective and injective. If $M $ and $N $ have the same finite cardinality then surjectivity gives injectivity for free. Surjectivity is not sufficient for a function to be invertible.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler, I would never have thought that the axiom of choice was involved in this issue. Maybe this consideration is a little above the level of the OP ...

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is surjective is there is a map $g:N\to M$ with $f\circ g=\text{id}_N$.
At least if you believe the axiom of choice, of which this is a form.
This type of one-sided inverse is called a *section* of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=\{0\}$. Then there is exactly one map $f$ from $M$ to $N$ (sending everything to $0$), and this has no inverse. If $g: \{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}$ was an inverse, then we'd have $g(f(x))=x = g(0)$. But then $g(0)$ is equal to infinitely-many things, which is absurd.

However, every surjection does have a *right* inverse, though this uses the Axiom of Choice.